# Where to begin with PostgreSQL trigger on update?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, triggers

I have a foreign table in my postgresql dB, the table has an update field that stores the timestamp when a task gets completed. I want to be able to insert the record from the foreign table into a database my local table at the moment the timestamp value changes. Normally I would just write a stored procedure that runs every x minutes but I would like this to happen real time. Is this something a trigger can do for me and can you point in the direction of a good example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want an after update trigger:

```
create function do_stuff() returns trigger as $$
begin
  -- do sql stuff here, e.g.:
  -- insert into foo (bar) select new.bar;
  return null;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;

create trigger do_stuff after update on yourtable
for each row when (new.stamp is distinct from old.stamp)
execute do_stuff();
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtrigger.html

Comment: Your example worked great for me, this was also very educational http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html